# Why so many autosuggestions?

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

When I want to traverse between directories, zsh is throwing a screenfull of tab completions. It's making the experience very bad. How can I get only few suggestions?

Comment: You mean `cd` completions are numerous? What's in your `PATH`?

Comment: Yeah cd completions. I am using Ubuntu on wsl2 and my path contains windows directories too.. okay, there's all the mess coming from. How can I not get cd completions from windows folders?

Comment: Do you need the windows folders in your PATH? If not, remove them. There may also be a `CDPATH` variable. Any excess directories in there?

Comment: CDPATH is empty. How do I remove windows folders from path? Can you guide me please?

Comment: You simply set `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/some/other/dir` in your `.zshrc`. You can test if this has any effect on the command line first with `OLD=$PATH`, `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:...`, `rehash`. Undo with `PATH=$OLD`.

Comment: Thank you @Jens. I finally set my path to only /bin. And now completions are a bit cleaner.

Comment: Only `/bin` might be a bit underpowered. It's better to use the system default, which you can query with `getconf PATH` and set with `PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning the comment conversation into an answer.

1. Check your `PATH` and `CDPATH` variables for directories you don't need.
2. Assign stripped down values somewhere in your `.zshrc`.
3. A good value for `PATH` is the system default, `PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)`.
4. Add to your liking, maybe `$HOME/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` if they exist.